# IE7 Bug flow right

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to fix a couple of problems when you view this web page in IE7.

(the web page looks great in iE8 and iE9)

I have uploaded the single web page onto a test site:

http://www.jrdesign-website.co.uk/bar_menu/bar_menu.html

When the page has loaded, scroll down to view. You will see the prices on the right hand side. The small duplicated full stops should line up with the prices and food description.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: thank you for your reply kikicarbonell.  Sorry I should have mentioned that I am a total beginner - can you be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

SO your code has a  with the dots underline on it as a repeating background and within that there is a wrapper div floated left with the food item name and nested within a that a  class .bar_font_bold_med which is 'float: right'.

Two possible ways of getting to a solution.
1\ Why not have the price i.e. the  in its own  instead. That will sort out the positioned-on-the right goal. It will also allow you to use  or middle or top etc on the price to independently adjust its vertical position in relation to the food item. Also use CSS to supply the dotted underline. Eg consider using a border-style on the lefthand  thus. 
`border-bottom: 5px dotted #fff`

How you attach the style is up to you. Perhaps a CSS classname on the relevant s is the best way i.e.

```
<td align="left" width="565" height="xxx" 
    bgcolor="#000000" background="images/yellow_dot.jpg"
```

... becomes...

```
<td class="foodItemCol" height="xxx">
```

...and you have the CSS styles

```
.foodItemCol {
    border-bottom: 5px dotted #ffffff;
    width: 565px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Or if you go with my suggestion of having another  for the price then use this CSS selelector which means you will not have to bother adding a classname

```
#bar_menu_text table td {
    border-bottom: 5px dotted #ffffff;
    width: 565px;
    background-color: #000000;
}

#bar_menu_text table td + td {
    border-bottom: none;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

What the second style selector is saying where the second or subsequent  sibling appears after the first  then overwrite the styles that where applied in the '#bar_menu_text table td' rule above i.e. so the price column does not have a dotted underline.
PS You have used a WYSIWYG editor to generate the code for this page haven't you? I have modified my answer baring that in mind as I guess you aren't used to coding HTML /CSS by hand.
PPS you don't need the z-index:5 or any z-index's at all whatsoever...they are only useful when the element the are applied to is position: relative or position: absolute etc.